# Can't log in to phpMyAdmin after removing MySQL root password

Tags: mysql, localhost, phpmyadmin

I get this messege:
`#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

I tried changing the password in phpMyAdmin `config.inc.php`
from `root` to `''` but all I got was
`Cannot connect: invalid settings.`

Comment: Are you running mysql on localhost of the server where phpmyadmin source code is residing? If yes, then the answer by @toomanyairmiles will probably solve your issue.